# pointer being freed was not allocated(delete one element in an array)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I am a beginner of oop, here is my question

```
int main(){
        int *p = new int[3];
        p[0] = 1;
        p[1] = 2;
        p[2] = 3;
        int* q = p;
        p++;  //here!
        delete p;
}
```

and

```
int main(){
        int *p = new int[3];
        p[0] = 1;
        p[1] = 2;
        p[2] = 3;
        int* q = p + 1;
        p++;  //here!
        delete p;
}
```

got bugs: pointer being freed was not allocated
but
and

```
int main(){
        int *p = new int[3];
        p[0] = 1;
        p[1] = 2;
        p[2] = 3;
        int* q = p + 1;
        delete p;
}
```

seems fine!
I want to delete one element in this array. Can someone tell me the reason for the bug?

Comment: You can't delete one element. The whole array has been allocated dynamically. You have to delete the whole thing.

Comment: You're first two snippets are invoking `operator delete` on an address that was not *returned* from `operator new`. This is **undefined behavior**. Your last snippet is not legal, as it doesn't invoke `operator delete[]` on an address returned from `operator new[]`, and even if it did you're address is `q` is then invalid.

Comment: Good comments, guys, but we should also inform OP that the way to properly deallocate the array is with the `delete []` operation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Memory is allocated in contiguous blocks, and must be returned in the same way. It is best to assume that your memory block comes with a small prefix that the allocator uses to determine where it came from and how large it was.

Also, when you "new" an array, you must use "delete []" to release it.

```
thing* thingArray = new thing[64];

...

delete [] thingArray;
```

If you are trying to actively manage the array of elements, you may want to investigate a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(10);
v.push_back(20);
v.push_back(30);
// v.size() is now 3 (num elements)
v.erase(v.begin()); // remove the first integer.
// v now "looks" like { 20, 30 }
// v.size() is now 2, not 3.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. To clarify, does that mean I malloc 3 ints, so that I have to delete the 3 ints together?

Comment: If they are 3 independent ints, then you should allocate and release them separately. Otherwise, just keep a pointer to the array and release that with 'delete []' when you are done with all of the elements.

Comment: Now I understand that. Thanks so much for sharing!

Comment: +1 on the vector sample. If the OP is doing a ton of mid-segment insertions and deletions, a `std::list<>` may actually be a proper fit as well, but for smaller segments, `std::vector` is likely all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`delete` is used for deallocation of dynamically allocated memory (by `new`). `delete` is not used for deleting elements. 
The bug is the following: firstly you allocated memory so after `int *p = new int[3];` in `p` pointer is memory address of the allocated space. Then you add 1 to this address in the `p++` line, which means that `p` is pointing now to different place in memory. Then your `delete` fails because you try to deallocate memory at the modified address.